# Concerning this situation, how many tires should be replaced?

Tags: tires

While glancing at my spouse's car tires, I noticed a nail in the front left tire. Seems like air doesn't come out of that tire. 
I then took a look at all tires and saw that the 2 front tires have holes expansion / tears (picture added below).

All of the tires are the same model of "Falken" brand and were bought around 3 years ago.

Should I: just fix the front left tire / replace 2 front tires / replace all tires ?
What might have caused the holes expansion / tears in the front tires? If it's something in the car, maybe I should fix it.

Photo 1 - Front tires view from above
[image: front above]

Photo 2 - Front tires view from the side
[image: front side]

Photo 3 - Back tires view from above
[image: back above]

Photo 4 - Back tires view from the side
[image: back side]

Answer (score 1):

That damage looks like the result of either a very bad alignment or doing burnouts. You should check the alignment and condition of the front suspension.

In addition to that, I can see signs of dry rot in the tires. Notice all the cracks in the low spots in the side of the tread? While it's not too bad yet, that means these tires are on the way out. I would suggest replacing all four sooner than later.